# Stop any program from running twice

Tags: windows

Does anyone know of a program that you can pipe a path and arguments to that first checks if the program is running and if so brings it to the foreground instead of running it twice?

Comment: What's the application?

Answer (score 6):

This kind of behaviour really should be built into the program itself using a mutex. It can be done with a fairly simple watchdog program but I don't know of a pre-built one. You also need to be aware that not all programs play nicely, so there's no guarantee the method will work with them all.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does this, almost -- when you try to launch another instance, it tries to open a new window from the running instance instead.  Which is exceptionally annoying when you are ssh'd into your workstation and want to run a new firefox, not open a new window on your (inaccessible) desktop.

These detection tricks are done in the firefox launcher script -- do a *which firefox* and start chewing through that.

Oh, you might ask on Stack Overflow too.